# What is the correct word to the song that kept telling me its okay or that keep telling is correct

Tags: word-choice, phrase-meaning, word-order, sequence-of-tenses

Like something I've been listening for a year and want to express that the song was the one that keep me going and what should be the correct word for me to post with kept telling or keep telling what should i use?

Comment: "The song **has kept** me going all year.  It **keeps telling me** (or **has kept telling me**) that everything is OK."

Answer (score 1):

You can say *it kept telling me* or *it keeps telling me*. (Not *it keep telling me* - that would not be grammatical).

If you say *it keeps telling me*, that says that you are still listening and receiving the message.

If you say *it kept telling me*, you are choosing to focus on your experience in the past. That suggests that you are no longer listening (or no longer getting that message), but it not necessarily saying so: you may still be listening, but you are choosing to talk about the past rather than the present.